# Android webview turns black

Tags: android, listview, webview

Sir,

I am going to implement the listvieww using viewholder pattern to display the web content. When it comes to the implementation, some device turns black as follows. Is there any way I have to take cautions or amendments to prevent such issues ?

[image: ScreenShot]

The below is my code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Keeps reference to avoid future findViewById()
        ContactsViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.readpost_reply, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userName);

            //
            viewHolder.txContent = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.replycontent);
            //
            WebSettings settings = viewHolder.txContent.getSettings();
            settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

            settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            viewHolder.txContent.setFocusable(false);
            viewHolder.txContent.setClickable(true);
            viewHolder.txContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));


            viewHolder.txTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.replytime); 
            viewHolder.ivQuote = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.action_quote);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ContactsViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        final Content content = (Content) contacts.get(position);
        if (content != null) {
            viewHolder.txName.setText(content.getUsername());
            //  viewHolder.txEmails.setText(content.getContent());
            TextProcessor processor = BBProcessorFactory.getInstance().create();
            String htmlParsed = processor.process(content.getContent());
            for(int i = 0 ; i < hkgiconsCodes.length ; i++){
                htmlParsed = bbC.replace(htmlParsed, hkgiconsCodes[i], hkgiconsHTML[i]);
            }

            for(int i = 0 ; i < otherCodes.length ; i++){
                htmlParsed = bbC.replace(htmlParsed, otherCodes[i], otherHTML[i]);
            }
            htmlParsed =   bbC.replaceColor(htmlParsed, true);
            htmlParsed =   bbC.replaceColor(htmlParsed, false);


  System.out.println(htmlPreffix + htmlParsed + htmlSuffixString);
            viewHolder.txContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlPreffix + htmlParsed + htmlSuffixString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            viewHolder.txTime.setText(content.getTime());

            viewHolder.txName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            //viewHolder.txEmails.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            //          viewHolder.txTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            if(content.getSex().equals("male")){
                viewHolder.txName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else{
                viewHolder.txName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
...


    static class ContactsViewHolder {
        TextView txName;
        WebView txContent;
        TextView txTime;
        ImageView ivQuote;
    }
```

Even I have commented

```
viewHolder.txContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
```

and set the color same as the transparent , the black screen still occurs at Sony devices

Comment: You should look at where the black is coming from. My guess is the webview's background is transparent and `Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")` on the container is too. This leaves it to show whatever is at the very back (often times just black). So maybe explicitly telling the webview to make it's background white will help.

Comment: But I want the color exactly same as the one followed by the theme as previous